# Changing members of Q_GADGET from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to **propagate** `Q_GADGET` as a `Q_PROPERTY` **into QML, change it there and pass it back into C++**.
I have class that derives from `Q_OBJECT`, which has the `Q_GADGET` class as a member.

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGadgetClass bar READ bar WRITE setBar NOTIFY barChanged)
public:
 
    ...

    QGadgetClass bar() const { return bar_; }
    void setBar(const QGadgetClass &bar) { bar_ = bar; emit barChanged(); }

    ...

signals:
    void barChanged();

private:
    QGadgetClass bar_;
}
```

The `Q_GADGET` class looks like this:

```
class QGadgetClass
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(AnotherQGadgetClass test READ test WRITE setTest)
    ... // there are also properties ID & name
public:
    ...
    // QGadgetClass getMyself() const { return *this; } // function explained later

    AnotherQGadgetClass test() const { return test; }
    void setTest(const AnotherQGadgetClass &test) { test_ = test; }
    ...

private:
    AnotherQGadgetClass test_;
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QGadgetClass)
```

I am trying to access `Q_GADGET` from QML classic way like accessing a `Q_OBJECT`, but the setters are not called. If I get `AnotherQGadgetClass` via getter and change it's properties, the setters are called and everything works, but for some reason I cannot manipulate the `QGadgetClass`. My code in QML looks like this:

```
Item {
    property var bar: foo.bar
    function changeBar()
    {
        console.log(bar.name) // works
        console.log(bar.id) // works
        bar.name = "New name" // the WRITE function of Q_PROPERTY(name ...) is not called
        console.log(bar.name) // shows old name

        console.log(bar.test) // prints out AnotherQGadgetClass correctly
        var temp = bar.test // copies AnotherQGadgetClass correctly
        console.log(temp.name) // prints AnotherQGadgetClass's name
        temp.name = "New temp name" // setter is called
        console.log(temp.name) // prints new name
        bar.test = temp // constructor is NOT called
        console.log(bar.test) // prints out old AnotherQGadgetClass 

        // following code works and will be explained bellow this code
        var aa = bar.getMyself() // calls the "hackish" method
        console.log(aa.name) // prints out name of QGadgetClass
        aa.name = "New name" // calls the setter
        console.log(aa.name) // prints out new name
    }
}
```

I have done some research already, but found nothing but [this page](https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/AO3pv4Ma/setting-propery-values-on-q-gadget-based-objects-in-qml-possible). I have also found some very unpretty solution [here](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2017-June/027393.html) and it worked, but I find it very hacky.

Note that every `Q_GADGET` is declared as metatype via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(...)` & is registered before usage via `qRegisterMetaType<...>("...")`.

Is there any prettier solution to access `QGadgetClass` directly from QML, without need to call `getMyself()` method? Why are the `Q_GADGET` class setters not called?

Answer (score 0):

A Q_GADGET is always treated as a value type in QML: it must be passed by copying.  So the object that you manipulate in QML is not the same instance that you created in C++, and property changes aren't visible in the original.  Many related issues are linked from https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82443

Comment: That would mean that `AnotherQGadgetClass` would be treated same, but it's not. You can change it's properties, it's only the main object passed from C++ that acts that way. Also, getters are called normally in `QGadgetClass`, only setters are not functional.